# regexp_substr coalesce nulliff

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, coalesce, regexp-substr, nullif

I am trying to achieve extract the version number of an app. Some rows are missing the app version and i wanted to populate that as well.

| post_mobileappid | app_version |
| --- | --- |
| My someword 13.0.0 | 13.0.0 |
| MySomeWord 12.0 | 12.0 |

I have the following

MAX(cast(coalesce(nullif(regexp_substr(post_mobileappid, 'My *Some (\d*\.\d*)', 0, 1, 'e'),''),'0') as double precision)) AS app_version

I am only getting 0 in the app_version column.

Can I please ask if there are ways to extract the full version number and populate something if it is NULL.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Oracle SQL?  If so, then please update the tags on your question.

Comment: my apology. I am using AWS Redshift. I have updated the tagging. Thank you for your advice. I am new here.